# CPU/ memory utilization

Tags: oracle, query, cpu-usage

WE have a job running very slowly. And I required to produce the analysis of CPU/ memory utilization during that backup.Also need statustics around the database performance for that batch job.

How to do this, please help me on this.

Comment: sounds like you need to bring in a consultant, if you don't have these skills in-house

Comment: More details would help. Do you have OEM or some third-party monitoring tool. What edition, version, options/packs are you licensed for ? What is the job. howe long does it take. How long do you think it should take. What volume of data is being processed

Comment: What platform?  Unix based platform have a `sar` utility which can capture cpu, memory, and disk utilization data.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  What edition (enterprise, standard, etc.)?  Do you have the performance and tuning packs licensed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can start here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/part4.htm#g996847

Besides that the Oracle Enterprise Manager provides the quickest way to monitor a running process.  The most common problem is missing an index and the tuning advisor will point that out quickly.